# ReferenceError: contenuto_translated is not defined

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm stuck at this error that I get only if I run my laravel + vuejs in build mode.
Ihave a custom component with 3 input and I'm using it in a Quasar dialog. When I start typing inside one of these 3 inputs, it give me the error I wrote in the post title.
See code and details.

I have a custom component file (EditObjectTranslation_Singleline.vue)

```
<template>
    <q-dialog ref="dialogRef" @hide="onDialogHide">
      <q-card class="q-dialog-plugin">
        <!--
          ...content
          ... use q-card-section for it?
        -->
        <q-card-section>
            <div class="text-h6">{{ titolo }}</div>
            <q-form @submit.prevent="invia_form">
              <div>
                    <q-input outlined v-model="contenuto_campo" label="Contenuto CAMPO" class="mt-4 block w-full" :disable="true"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <q-input outlined v-model="contenuto_lingua_default" label="Contenuto Lingua IT" class="mt-4 block w-full" :disable="true"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <q-input outlined v-model="contenuto_translated" :label="label_translated" class="mt-4 block w-full" :maxlength="max_lunghezza"/>
                </div>
            </q-form>
        </q-card-section>  
        <!-- buttons example -->
        <q-card-actions align="right">
          <q-btn color="primary" label="OK" @click="onOKClick" />
          <q-btn color="primary" label="Cancel" @click="onDialogCancel" />
        </q-card-actions>
      </q-card>
    </q-dialog>
  </template>
  
  <script setup>
  import { useDialogPluginComponent } from 'quasar'
  import { computed } from '@vue/reactivity'

  const props = defineProps({
    contenuto_campo: '',
    contenuto_lingua_default: '',
    contenuto_translated: '',
    lingua: '',
    max_lunghezza: 0
  })

  const label_translated = computed (() => {
    return "Contenuto tradotto " + props.lingua
  })

  defineEmits([
    // REQUIRED; need to specify some events that your
    // component will emit through useDialogPluginComponent()
    ...useDialogPluginComponent.emits
  ])
  
  const { dialogRef, onDialogHide, onDialogOK, onDialogCancel } = useDialogPluginComponent()
  // dialogRef      - Vue ref to be applied to QDialog
  // onDialogHide   - Function to be used as handler for @hide on QDialog
  // onDialogOK     - Function to call to settle dialog with "ok" outcome
  //                    example: onDialogOK() - no payload
  //                    example: onDialogOK({ /*...*/ }) - with payload
  // onDialogCancel - Function to call to settle dialog with "cancel" outcome
  
  // this is part of our example (so not required)
  function onOKClick () {
    // on OK, it is REQUIRED to
    // call onDialogOK (with optional payload)
    onDialogOK(props)
    // or with payload: onDialogOK({ ... })
    // ...and it will also hide the dialog automatically
  }
  </script>
```

Then, I want to use the previous component as a custom component in a quasar dialog.
So the page code where I'm using the previous custom components follows

```
 <script setup>
  import AuthenticatedLayout from '@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout.vue';
  import { Inertia } from '@inertiajs/inertia';
  import { useQuasar } from 'quasar';
  import { ref } from 'vue';
  import { computed } from '@vue/reactivity';
  import { Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
  import CustomComponent from '@/Components/EditObjectTranslation_Singleline.vue';
  import axios from 'axios';

  const $q = useQuasar()

  const props = defineProps({
    catalogues: Array,
    lingue: Array,
    field2betranslated: Number
  })




const $qTranslate = useQuasar()
function onTranslateObject (pLingua) {

    if (selected.value.length > 0 ) {
      axios
        .get('/api/getTraduzioni/'+ pLingua  + '/' + selected.value[0].resource_id)
        .then((response) => {

        $q.dialog({
          component: CustomComponent,
          componentProps: {
            titolo: 'Traduci contenuti:',
            contenuto_campo: selected.value[0].name,
            contenuto_lingua_default: response.data.originale,
            contenuto_translated: response.data.tradotto,
            lingua: pLingua,
            max_lunghezza: 64,
            resource_id: selected.value[0].resource_id
            // ...more..props...
          }
        }).onOk((formData) => {
            // console.log('>>>> OK')
            translateObject(formData)
        }).onOk(() => {
            // console.log('>>>> second OK catcher')
        }).onCancel(() => {
            // console.log('>>>> Cancel')
        }).onDismiss(() => {
            // console.log('I am triggered on both OK and Cancel')
        })

      })
    } else {
        $q.dialog({
            title: 'Attenzione',
            message: 'Devi selezionare una riga'
      })
    }
}

</script>

<template>
    <Head :title="$t('cataloghi.pagetitle') " />

    <AuthenticatedLayout>

        <div class="q-py-xl">
          <!-- Pulsanti traduzioni -->
          <div class="w-full flex justify-end space-x-2 mb-4">
              <q-btn v-for="lingua in lingue" :label="lingua.codiceIso" :key="lingua.codiceIso"  @click="onTranslateObject(lingua.codiceIso)" icon="language" color="whte" text-color="text-grey-7" />
          </div>
        </div>

    </AuthenticatedLayout>
</template>
```

When I open the dialog and try to input in the "contenuto_translated" q-input I get this error:

```
"ReferenceError: contenuto_translated is not defined"
```

Surely I'm missing something.
Please help me.

Comment: Where does the error occur? On which line?

Comment: Hello @DanielW., as I wrote it is triggered only on built deploy, not in dev environment.
Exactly it shows this message ReferenceError: contenuto_translated is not defined
    at l.onUpdate:modelValue.a.<computed>.a.<computed> referencig build/assets/EditObjectTranslation_Singleline.59697534.js file at position 1:1369 As you can se it refers a built asset.